# Selenium + Jenkins: Missing location header

Tags: java, selenium, jenkins

I am trying to use Selenium Grid with Jenkins.
When I start Selenium Hub and Node with the server-standalone 2.35.0 jar, everything works perfect.
However, does not work when I use the Jenkins Selenium Grid Plugin as hub.

The Error appears here:

> driver = new RemoteWebDriver ( new URL ( gridURL ), capabilities );

grid URL is `"http://localhost:4444/wd/hub"`

capabilities is this:

```
DesiredCapabilities capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.firefox ();
capabilities.setPlatform ( Platform.LINUX );
```

This exception is thrown:

```
org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: Error forwarding the new session new session request for webdriver should contain a location header with the session.
Command duration or timeout: 25.28 seconds
Build info: version: '2.35.0', revision: '8df0c6bedf70ff9f22c647788f9fe9c8d22210e2', time: '2013-08-17 12:46:41'
System info: os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '3.8.0-31-generic', java.version: '1.7.0_40'
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver
```

As Hub I use the Jenkins Selenium Plugin Version 2.3
As Node I use selenium-server-standalone-2.35.0.jar.

When I open `http://localhost:4444/` with a browser, it says: `You are using grid 2.29.0`
So I downloaded selenium-server-standalone-2.29.0.jar and let it run as a hub. The node still is Version 2.35.0.
Then I've got the same exception. I tried node and hub with 2.29.0 but it seems that my Firefox is too new for this.

I searched several hours but didn't find anything regarding this error.

Edit:
The Plugin, which is installed by Jenkins, is from August, 18th 2013: https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Selenium+Plugin

The developer updated the plugin two days later on August, 20th 2013: https://github.com/jenkinsci/selenium-plugin/commit/316eccdef608e855863cf04b1c240fa2c7b8b762

I don't know if this is causing my errors, but it is possible. I don't know yet how to do this, but I'm going to try to build my own plugin version from the source code on github.

Comment: Could you show us your test class?  namely, anytime `WebDriver` is instantiated

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand you correctly.

The WebDriver gets instantiated directly before the told code snipped. I debugged the code and the exception is thrown when I try to create the new RemoteWebDriver.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I now know definitely what the problem is:

As I mentioned above the node is Selenium Version 2.35. The current Jenkins Selenium Plugin is Version 2.3 which uses Selenium 2.29. This is causing the error.

Now I used Selenium Version 2.29 as node. And installed Firefox Version 18. Now everything is working fine. I contacted the developer and I am trying to build the current Plugin Version from git. For now without success, but I think I'll open another thread for this.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

You can update the selenium version in the jenkins plugin, replace 2.29.0 with 2.39.0 in the below mentioned path:

[JenkinsFolder]\plugins\selenium\WEB-INF\lib

You will find the old jar here. replace it with the latest jar.
It will work fine.

Answer (score 0):

This error means that you have no nodes connected to the hub.  The Hub is **UP** and receiving connections, but is unable to forward the request to a node.

Make sure that you have nodes connected to your hub.  You can do this by --

```
java -jar selenium-server-2.29.0.jar -role node -hubUrl http://ip-of-hub:4444/wd/register
```

This command *may* be inaccurate.  Consult the official doc.

Comment: is the node your local computer?

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I do have connected a node to the hub. Command: `java -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.35.0.jar -role node -hub http://localhost:4444/grid/register` See Wiki: [link](https://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/Grid2)

I can see the hub in the Jenkings Selenium Plugin.

Comment: Yes, for now it is my local computer. Everything is running local.

Comment: How are you connecting the node? firefox will need access to an X session to display

Comment: Well, everything is running locally, so there is a X-Server on the sides of the hub and the node.